# Vscode: Don't have access to .venv python interpreter when venv is created in a subfolder

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, pipenv

There's an issue puzzling me, so this is the scenario:

- I create a clean folder and start VSCode in it.
- I create a subfolder (say 'server') **and cd into it** (VSC integrated terminal).
- I initialise a virtual environment and install my dependencies (I use Pipenv) so my tree so far looks like this:

```
    .
    └── server
        ├── .venv
        └── Pipfile
```

- I can see in my zsh prompt that indeed the virtual environment is active

[image: Prompt]

- However, I cannot find the interpreter for my virtual environment in the list of available ones:

[image: Interpreter missing]

(Note that `Python 3.9.1 64-bit ('server':pipenv)` is missing from the options)

- As a result, if I create for example a django app, I get warnings all over the place about imports not being resolved.

If I instead start VSCode **directly** in the `server` directory, I have no issues and I can select it:

[image: Interpreter found]

But this is not what I need, as I need to have access to both my backend and frontend in the same VSCode project.

Please note that I want to have my .venv folder inside `server` and not in the root of the project.

What's the point I'm missing and why am I unable to use/choose my .venv interpreter if I cd in the right directory?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried adding the path of the virtual environment you created to the python environment variable?

Comment: I do, by adding a relative path to my python symlink in the venv folder. But then I get "We removed the "python.pythonPath" setting from your settings.json file as the setting is no longer used by the Python extension." and the setting gets deleted...

Comment: You could try to add the path of the created virtual environment to the environment variables of the system, usually VS Code will recognize the environment from system variables well.